# ContextMenu in ListView shows up when clicking on column headers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, contextmenu

I made a ListView and a ContextMenu that pops up when I right click on the ListView. The problem is that it also pops up when right clicking on headers. What I want it to do is to only pop up when I right click on an item.

I already tried answers of other questions about this specific problem, but they didn't work for me.

This is the ListView I added. The menu should only show up in on the items.

[image: ListView]

And here is my code:

```
public GUIMod CreateList
{
    set
    {
        ListView1.Items.Clear();

        bool latestCompatibleVersionAlreadyFound = false;
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(AllVersions.Select(module =>
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            if (module.IsCompatible(versionCriteria))
            {
                if (!latestCompatibleVersionAlreadyFound)
                {
                    latestCompatibleVersionAlreadyFound = true;
                    item.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    item.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                }
            }

            if (installedVersion != null && installedVersion.IsEqualTo(module.version))
            {
                item.Font = new Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            }

            item.Text = module.version.ToString();
            item.SubItems.Add(module.HighestCompatibleVersion());
            return item;
        }
        ).ToArray());
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ListView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Item;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            // Show the right click menu
            ContextMenuStrip1.Show(ListView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            if (installedVersion != null && AllVersions[item.Index].version.IsEqualTo(installedVersion))
            {
                // Item is darkgreen, disable option
                ToolstripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (!AllVersions[item.Index].IsCompatible(versionCriteria))
            {
                // Item is white, disable option
                ToolstripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Item is installable, enabe option
                ToolstripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ToolstripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Nothing yet
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what specifically doesn't work in the answers you have reviewed? Also I suggest to use the Opening event handler to cancel the opening of the context menu.

Comment: I tried using `Bounds`, `FocusedItem`, `SelectedItems`, ... but al these still let the right click menu show up on the headers.

Comment: Weird, I cannot get a MouseDown event if I click on the header of the ListView.

Comment: Could you try with _var item = ListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);_ instead of HitTest?

Comment: I tried it but it still pops up when clicking on headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `FullRowSelect` to `true`. Then handle `MouseClick` event and check if the right mouse button has been clicked, perform a hit-test and if there is an item under the mouse, first select it and then show the `ContextMenuStrip` this way:

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button== MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hti.Item != null)
            hti.Item.Selected = true;

        contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView1, e.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem applying the solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. This also was one of the answers I found when looking for this problem.

Comment: I tested it and it works properly. Probably you didn't copied the code and didn't test in a clean environment. Give it a try in a clean environment and copy the exact code to see the result. Pay attention it's `MouseClick` event.

Comment: I copied the code and changed my event from `MouseDown` to `MouseClick`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What's the meaning of doesn't work? Doesn't show menu? Doesn't select the item? What happens? Are you sure you attached the event handler to the event? It's quiet simple to prove it's working in a clean environment...

Comment: I mean that still shows the menu when clicking on the headercolumn. It does work correctly when clicking on the items, but when I click on the header, it shows the menu with the information of the last clicked item.

Comment: Surely the problem is with your test. Because `if (hti.Item != null)` prevents from showing the menu when you right click on headers. Also this line `hti.Item.Selected = true;` sets the clicked item as selected. It seams you are not trying the solution in a clean environment. I double checked the solution simply in a new form using a new list view and I can confirm it's working properly.

Comment: I didn't try this in clean environment, no. The project is 2 years old and I'm improving it with a right click menu. I updated the OP so that it includes all the methods of the file.

Comment: Answering a question needs [MCVE]. All users are going to help you solve problems but they are not going to write your business logic codes. The question should be remain clean for future users. That's why you should ask question about clean environment and test them in clean environment. After you proved the answer is working, then it's your job to apply it on your old project.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, that's why I left out all the other code. This listview is a new form, I added it myself (it's one of the improvements). Then I wanted to add a right click function but that didn't work, even after searching and applying other answers.

Comment: @ArnePeirs The answer is definitely correct and I'm not sure why/how you can not test it in a clean environment!

Comment:  After more than two years! 

Answer (score 0):

The MouseDown (I prefer mouseup for showing a context menu) event has a MouseEventArgs parameter, a property of which is the location where the mouse was clicked. This can be used to determine where he mouse was i.e. If it was in the header, and if so, cancel the mouseup evwnt. The location of the mouse may be specified relative to the list box control or the form itself, so check and adjust the logic accordingly (I can't remember which coordinate system it uses)